# Módulos offline em Nodejs com npmbox

Tags: node.js

Eu sei que é possível gerenciar os módulos do node estando offline através do npmbox. Mas como faço isso? É necessário baixar os módulos antes? É preciso instala-los em um diretório diferente do projeto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `npmbox` vem com dois executáveis:

- `npmbox <nome-do-pacote> <nome-de-outro-pacote>…`
- `npmunbox <nome-do-box>`

## Criando arquivos `.npmbox` com o NPMBOX

Para criar um bundle de um pacote, com todas as suas dependências embutidas, você deve executar:

```
npmbox <pacote>
```

Por exemplo:

```
npmbox express
```

Busca por todas as dependencias do express e as combina em um arquivo `express.npmbox` no diretório atual.

Você pode passar vários nomes de pacotes ao mesmo tempo e vários arquivos `.npmbox` vão ser criados, um para cada pacote.

## Usando os arquivos `.npmbox` com o NPMUNBOX

Uma vez que se tenha um arquivo `.npmbox`, executar:

```
npmunbox <box>
```

Vai extrair o *box* para dentro da pasta `node_modules` no diretório atual. Por exemplo, se executarmos:

```
npmbox express
# ^ O arquivo express.npmbox é criado 
npmunbox express.npmbox
# ^ O arquivo express.npmbox é extraído e o express é instalado no node_modules
```

Verificaremos que um diretório `node_modules` é criado, com o `express` instalado dentro dele.

## Automatizando a criação/extração de boxes para um pacote local

Não há uma maneira, hoje, nem de criar um único *box* com vários pacotes, nem de criar um box para uma aplicação inteira automaticamente. Isso não é muito difícil de consertar. Segue um script que geraria um *box* para cada dependência em um projeto:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var child_process = require('child_process');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var pkgJson = require(
  process.argv[2] ||
  path.join(process.cwd(), 'package.json')
);

var pkgName = pkgJson.name || 'package';
var pkgDeps = Object.keys(pkgJson.dependencies || {})
  .concat(Object.keys(pkgJson.devDependencies || {}));
console.log(pkgDeps);

var targetDir = path.join(process.cwd(), pkgName + '-npmboxes');

if(!fs.existsSync(targetDir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(targetDir);
}

var c = child_process.spawn('npmbox', pkgDeps, {
  stdio: 'inherit',
  cwd: targetDir,
});

c.on('close', function(code) { process.exit(code); });
```

Ele poderia ser usado da seguinte forma:

```
./script.js <localização de um package.json>
```

O que criaria um diretório `<nome-do-pacote-no-package.json>-npmboxes` com todos os *boxes* para esse pacote. Desempacota-los depois não seria muito mais difícil do que:

```
cd <nome-do-pacote-no-package.json>-npmboxes
for b in *; do npmunbox $b; done
```